# How to Connect Bitbucket repos to Google cloud source repository using REST API

Tags: google-apis-explorer, google-cloud-build

I'm using cloud build service for Continuous Integration and able to create bitbucket mirror in google cloud source repository but, I want to mirror all bitbucket repos to cloud source repository.
I dont want to create manually all the time.

I saw [Rest API to Create mirror repos][1] this. but no idea how to do it.

below is body I have to pass to create mirror repos. please help me.

````
{
  "name": "",
  "size": 0,
  "url": "",
  "mirrorConfig": {
    "deployKeyId": "",
    "url": "",
    "webhookId": ""
  },
  "pubsubConfigs": {}
}```


  [1]: https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.repos/create
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey @SHASHIKUMARKL have expereminted your idea using the rest api using the endpoint `/v1/projects.repos/create` , However, it won't work because the mirrorConfig properity [is read only field](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.repos#Repo.FIELDS.mirror_config). so you cannot change it to automate the process of mirroring between GCP and BitBucket. This endpoint `/v1/projects.repos/create` is intended to create repos not to mirror them. The only way to mirror repos is one by one following [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/mirroring-a-bitbucket-repository)